# Convert SVG element to img

Tags: javascript, html

None of related issues has the answer.
I want to get my SVG drawing from the DOM, and convert it to being an img.

This is how my function looks now

```
const SVG = document.querySelector('svg')!;
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

const XML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(SVG);
const SVG64 = btoa(XML);
const image64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + SVG64;

const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  canvas.getContext('2d')!.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};

img.src = image64;

document.getElementById('container')!.appendChild(img);
```

And the DOM

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
   <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" />
</svg>

<div id="container"></div>
```

The result is a blank image. It do has a dataurl as src, but completely blank. Why is that? How should it work?

Answer (score 3):

Watch errors:

```js
const SVG = document.querySelector('svg')!;
const XML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(SVG);
const SVG64 = btoa(XML);

const img = new Image();
img.height = 500;
img.width = 500;
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + SVG64;

document.getElementById('container')!.appendChild(img);
```

```html
SVG:<br/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
   <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" />
</svg>

<hr/>

<div id="container" style="background: red;">
</div>
```

Seems like You've issue with `!` marks:
`document.querySelector('svg')!`, `canvas.getContext('2d')!`, `document.getElementById('container')!` - why?

As good practice open inspector panel, console tab of browser to see error messages.

After long talk I understood that Your js code is placed above html elements.

So try to do rendering after window loaded.

Check this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  renderSVG();
}

const renderSVG = function() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const svg = document.querySelector('svg');

  if (container && svg) { // since You want to check existence of elements
    const XML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
    const SVG64 = btoa(XML);

    const img = new Image();
    img.height = 500;
    img.width = 500;
    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + SVG64;

    container.appendChild(img);
  }
};
```

```html
SVG:<br/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
   <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" />
</svg>

<hr/>

<div id="container" style="background: red;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. But I have to figure out why the object may possibly be null if i remove '!'. Btw, Im working in React

Comment: @jonask added `if` check

Comment: Still gets a blank img after the if check is added

Comment: @jonask see my answer, it works, Your issue is that You use exclamation mark. I've checked my code in: Chrome, Safari, Opera, Mozilla

Comment: Yes I can see the snippet is working well. But it doesn't even if I copy paste it. Can't figure out why

Comment: @jonask open inspector panel, console tab as in this screenshot and find reason why: http://joxi.ru/GrqVVZh4NJbEmz

Comment: Well, it returns 'undefined' in the console and nothing changes.

Comment: @jonask seems like You've issue in different place, cause if You'll create an html with content as in my answer and open it, it will work. So Your issue cannot be predicted.

Comment: check these examples: http://anarjafarov.me/svg-js-before-html.html  http://anarjafarov.me/svg-js-after-html.html  http://anarjafarov.me/svg-js-before-html-onload.html

Comment: I do not doubt that it works well and it clearly makes sense. I'm looking for why it won't work with my code, cause its not much different.